# Shutdown splash not working

Tags: greeter, shutdown, logo

When shutting down Elementary 6 Odin, the splashscreen is not presented but instead it is showing the shutdown command text. This is following a fresh install from flash. On startup it is set to quiet launch with no logo splash or commands.

---

Keno's answer worked, Thank you.
I also updated my graphics drivers with:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

In fact it may be worth updating your intel drivers first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the same issue I had, but you don't use disk encryption so you just see a black screen shortly on boot and then are greeted by the login manager.

See here for my solution: [Black screen instead of plymouth](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/black-screen-instead-of-plymouth)

(Sorry, I can't post this as a comment because I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Was this with Elementary 6 Odin? (I see you also used a Lenovo, I'm using a X1 1st Gen.)

Comment: @ShannonButler Yes it was with Odin. I'm going to clarify this in my question.